# How to generate checkboxes dynamically in a Google Calendar add-on card?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm developing a Google Calendar add-on to list all events from selected calendars. Now I can get the calendar list of current user but I don't know how to generate a group of checkboxes of them.

```
var calendar = CardService.newSelectionInput()
.setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
.setTitle("Please choose the calendars.")
.setFieldName("calendar")
.addItem("common calendar", "commonCalendar",false)
.addItem("sales department calendar","salesDepartmentCalendar", false)
.addItem("development department calendar", "developmentDepartmentCalendar",false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to add checkboxes for each calendar in your calendar list,

**You can try this sample code:**

```
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setName("Card name")
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Card title"));
  
  var widget = CardService.newSelectionInput()
  .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
  .setTitle("Please choose the calendars.")
  .setFieldName("calendar");
  
  var calendarList = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  Logger.log("Calendar Count:" + calendarList.length);
  
  
  //Add checkbox per calendar
  for (var i = 0; i < calendarList.length; i++) {
    var calendar = calendarList[i];
    Logger.log("calendar"+i);
    
    //Add Calendar as Item
    widget.addItem(calendar.getName(), "calendar"+i,false)
  }
  
  var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader("Section header").addWidget(widget);
  return card.addSection(cardSection).build();
```

**Procedure:**

1. Create a [card](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card?hl=en) with title "Card title".
2. Create a [selection input](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input?hl=en) with field name "calendar".
3. Loop your calendar list, add an item to your [selection input](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input?hl=en) based on the calendar name for each calendar in your list. Create an [addItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input#additemtext,-value,-selected) `value` parameter based on the calendar loop index (calendar0, calendar1, .... )
4. Add the [selection input](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input?hl=en) as widget using [addWidget()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-section?hl=en#addwidgetwidget) in the [card section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-section?hl=en).
5. Add section to the card and build the card.

**Sample Output:**

[image]